# get cells in range and paste as values Apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a range `A2:Z5000` that i am trying to paste as values in the same exact range (turn formulas into fixed values)

In range `A2` i have a `ImportData` formula fetching data from a csv file.

My script goes like:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('MYSQLimport');
sheet.getRange("A2:Z5000").copyTo(sheet.getRange("A2:Z5000"), {contentsOnly:true});
```

but it erases the content instead of setting it as values...

Comment: Tested it here and it worked. It may soud weird, but are you sure you're getting the values from the right sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description

copyTo copies the contents being values and/or formulas you need to gettValues()/setValues().

Script

```
var values = sheet.getRange("A2:Z5000").getValues();
sheet.getRange("A2:Z5000").setValues(values);
```